# Get order Items in a pipe seperated string

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I'm needing to set up some tracking on a Magento store (1.4.1), and hoped someone may have achieved this previously!

Basically, I need to create a string variable from the order confirm page that contains the ordered items, and requires each item in the string to be separated by the pipe symbol (|) and each property of each item must be separated by two colons (::).

Also, if the same item is purchased multiple times in the same order, they need to be treated as multiple individual items as the recipient of the string does not support the qty variable.

An example of the string format required would be:

```
$purchased_items="1234::9.99::CD Album::CD002345|1255::12.99::James Bond DVD::DVD001234::ABCD123|1255::12.99::James Bond DVD::DVD001234::ABCD123";
```

I'm hoping someone has previously implemented a similar solution - Many Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Answer (score 0):

here's some meta code (not tested) pass the correct order object

```
//we need a buffer
$stringArray = array();

//and we need to iterate over all objects (note that they are objects)
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $item){
    //add your formatted strings to buffer array by imploding the product information array
    $stringArray[]= implode('::',$item->getProduct()->getData());
}

//$string will contain the stuff you need to echo
$string = implode('|', $stringArray); 

$stringArray = null;
```